# Postfix - recipient_delimiter to mail folder

Tags: postfix, dovecot

I am using postfix, the LDA is dovecot and i found the useful parameter `recipient_delimiter` in the man page of postfix.

I would like to use mail addresses like `user+folder@domain.com` and the mail server should automatically move the mail into the appropriate folder. If the folder does not exist, it should get created.

Dovecot can create automatically directories over the configuration files. I have found the following options for it: [Mailbox Settings](https://wiki.dovecot.org/MailboxSettings) and [Autocreate Plugin](https://wiki2.dovecot.org/Plugins/Autocreate)

So i could write a little bash scripts which reads the mail server logs, greps the mail addresses and either create the maildirectory via mkdir or via the dovecot configuration. But i do not believe that this is the correct solution for it, because:

1. The first mail would not get catched because the mail folder
   does not exist at this time. But that is not the main problem, the mail could get moved via the script too.
2. There must be a better solution for that.

I searched already on the web, but i could not find informations about that. Probably (for sure) i am using the false searching terms.

Comment: I use the same setting to allow my mail client to do the filtering into subfolders.  I also use a hyphen ( - ) instead of a plus since a lot of forum registrations (and my bank) think the plus ( + ) isn't a valid character in an email address.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Doevecot supports Sieve filters](https://wiki2.dovecot.org/Pigeonhole/Sieve) to handle incoming mail. By combining the [`fileinto` module](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5228#section-4.1), the [`:create` option of the mailbox module](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5490#section-3.2) and finally the [subaddress extension](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5233) you will be able to sort mails by their extension into different folders.

This will move all mails to `<user>+<tag>@example.org` to `$tag` subdirectories in the `tag` folder of the inbox.

```
require ["fileinto", "mailbox", "subaddress", "envelope", "variables"];
if envelope :matches :detail "to" "*" {
  fileinto :create "inbox.tags.${1}";
}
```

Comment: Note: I have not verified this very snippet, but constructed it from some other parts of my own Sieve script. If there are any issues, please post the error message.

Comment: I can confirm it works as intended.

Answer (score 0):

I followed your instruction, too. I basically works, but for some reason I am not able to see the newly created  folders in my Email clients, like Thunderbird for Linux Desktop and Fairmail on Android.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y3128.png)

Under 1 Sieve created folders as per your code. I then removed inbox.tags. from code just to see what will happen. A different folder was created after email came in, but I cannot see that one either. Any idea what the reason could be?

Comment: Needed to restart Thunderbird for some reason. Works great now. Thanks

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://serverfault.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://serverfault.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/565480)